# Pytorch: layer not transferred on GPU with to() function

Tags: python, pytorch, nvidia, tensor

In the following code, I expected tensor `x` and layer `l` both on GPU, instead only the the tensor `x` results to be on the GPU, and not the layer `l`. In fact, using this approach results in `RuntimeError: Expected all tensors to be on the same device, but found at least two devices, cpu and cuda:0!` during a learning stage.

```
import torch
x = torch.zeros(1)
x = x.to('cuda')
try:
    x.get_device()
    print('x: gpu')
except:
    print('x:','cpu')

l = torch.nn.Linear(1,1)
l = l.to('cuda')
try:
    l.get_device()
    print('l: gpu')
except:
    print('l:','cpu')
```

the output is:

```
x: gpu
l: cpu
```

instead of both `gpu`.
why this?

Torch version: 1.10.2+cu113

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't call `.get_device()` on a `nn.Linear` object, therefore your second try block fails and it prints the code in the exception part. In order to check what device your module is on you can do the following:

```py
print(next(l.parameters()).device)
```

output:

```
>> device(type='cuda', index=0)
```